Как передать в RegisterHotKey() несколько кнопок? C#
Например я хочу чтобы код выполнялся при нажатии горячих клавиш CTRL+WIN+S, как мне передать в fsModifers метода RegisterHotKey() две кнопки (ctrl и win)?

fsModifers работает как битовая маска, передавайте MOD_CONTROL | MOD_WIN
